# Is it possible to get Auth::user in lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to make a login screen in my app. But it seems impossible to do it in lumen!

These example would work in laravel, but wont in lumen:

login:

```
// Not working
Auth::login($user);
```

getting auth user:

```
if(Auth::check()){
  $user = Auth::user();
}
```

Above example seems impossible to do in lumen, if there's a way to do that please show me! Thank you

Comment: You should use JWT token to authenticate users in API.

Comment: I don't fully understand. You are trying to check if the user is authenticated. If so, you trying to login with the already logged in user?

Comment: After cheking if the user is authenticated, I'm trying to get user data! But not having success!

Comment: Lumen has its own documentation, specifically on [authentication](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/authentication). Did you read that?

Comment: Yes, I did! But didnt help me!

Comment: Note that Lumen is supposed to be a stateless API framework for creating microservices. If you're adding screens and creating a whole app, it's probably a better idea to switch to Laravel.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426340/user-authentication-in-lumen

Answer (score 3):

Source: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

```
   Note: If you would like to use Auth::user() to access the currently authenticated user, 
   you should uncomment the $app->withFacades() method in your bootstrap/app.php file.

   Note: Before using Lumen's authentication features, you should uncomment the call to 
   register the AuthServiceProvider service provider in your bootstrap/app.php file.
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why this is "not working".

Did you import Auth at the beginning of the file?

```
use Auth;
```

Uncomment (remove `//` from) the following line in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
// $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

Also if you have user's credentials, try using `Auth::attempt()`:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
```

Official docs:
1. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication
2. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication

Try posting some error messages in you question, if there are any. That would take out the guessing part.